# How do you export the data from a Nagios XI service to a file

Tags: export, snmp, nagios, nagiosxi

We want to export the value of a service to a file, that updates, so we can display it elsewhere.

We have Nagios XI on a CentOS virtual machine that monitors a host using SNMP. The status of the service can be, for example, 0 or 1. We want that value in a file on our computer, so that we can display it using another program.

Comment: You can use your own queries send to Nagios socket file. https://checkmk.com/cms_livestatus.html